# React utilizando Redux, nao esta salvando estado da aplicacao

Tags: react, redux

Estou tentando implementar `redux` na minha `app` Web `react`, não da nenhum erro mas tambem não funciona, quando tento capturar estado fica como `undefined`

estrutura:

- App.js
- routes.js
- store/actions.js
- store/index.js
- store/reducers/index.js
- store/reducers/posts.js
- pages/Main.js

---

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import Routes from './routes';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Routes />
    </Provider> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";

import Main from './pages/Main';
import Detalhe from './pages/Detalhe';

import history from "./history";

export default function Routes(){
    return (        
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
            <Route path="/posts/:id" exact component={Detalhe} />
        </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    );
}
```

---

store/index.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from "redux";
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from "connected-react-router";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import history from "../history";
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [
    routerMiddleware(history),
    thunk
];


const store = createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
  initialState,
  compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware)
  )
);

export default store;
```

---

store/actions.js

```
import { push } from "connected-react-router";

export const dataSave = (posts) => dispatch => ({

  type: "ADD_POSTS",
  payload: { posts }

});
```

---

store/reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import posts from "./posts";

export default combineReducers({
  posts
});
```

---

store/reducers/posts.js

```
export default function posts(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_POSTS":
        return {...state, posts: action.payload.posts };        
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

---

pages/Main.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Main.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Navbar2 from '../components/Navbar';
import {isMobile} from 'react-device-detect';
import api from '../services/api';

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as DataActions from "../store/actions";
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

function Main({ history, match, dataSave, posts }){ 

   /* Nao e mais um state local */
   // const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    let [page] = useState(1);

    /*
    if (localStorage.getItem("posicaoScroll") === undefined &&
        localStorage.getItem("posicaoScroll") === null
      ) {
        localStorage.setItem("posicaoScroll", JSON.stringify(0));
      }
    */  

    const [layout, setLayout] = useState(null);

    /*
    const [posicao, setPosicao] = useState(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("posicaoScroll"))
      );
    */  

    useEffect(() => {
      async function loadDados(){

        const response = await api.get('/posts?_start=0&_limit=10'); 

        //Agora seta via redux
        //setPosts(response.data);

        console.log('Get da API');
        console.log(response.data);

        dataSave(response.data); 

        //Teoricamente era para aparecer os posts no console agora
        console.log('Estado no Redux');
        console.log(posts);

        page = 1;

        if (isMobile) {
          setLayout('mob');   
        } else {    
          setLayout('web');
        }

        /*
        let scrollpos = localStorage.getItem("posicaoScroll");
        if (scrollpos !== undefined && scrollpos !== null) {
            // Timeout necessário para funcionar no Chrome 
            if (scrollpos <= 100)
            scrollpos = 0;
            console.log(scrollpos); //JSON.parse(scrollpos)
            setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);
            }, 1);
        } 
        */


      };

      loadDados();

    }, []);

    /*
    useEffect(() => {       
      // Verifica mudanças no Scroll e salva no localStorage a posição 
       window.onscroll = function(e) {
        setPosicao(window.scrollY);
        localStorage.setItem("posicaoScroll", JSON.stringify(posicao));
      }           

        return () => {};
      }, [posicao, page, setPosicao]);
    */


    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }, []);


    /* Scroll infinito nao ta funcionando pq nao ta disparando evento ao chegar no final da pagina, talvez calculo esteja errado */
    async function handleScroll() {

        console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);

         //if (((document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (page * window.innerHeight)) / page >= 5.80) {
        if (((document.documentElement.scrollTop) / 1350) >= page) {

            page = page + 1;

            //Comentei para nao da erro
            fetchMoreListItems(page - 1);

        } else {
            return;
        }
    }  

    async function fetchMoreListItems(pagecount) {        

        const response = await api.get(`/posts?_start=${pagecount * 10}&_limit=10`);       

        //Agora seta via Redux
        //setPosts(prevState => ([...prevState, ...response.data]));    
        dataSave(response.data); // Isso é equivalente a linha acima?

    }

    //------

    return (
        <div className="main">           

        <Navbar2/>

               <div className="main-container">        

                    { posts.length > 0 ? (
                    <ul id="ullist" className={"main-container ul"+layout}> 
                        {posts.map(post => (
                            <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`} >
                                <li id="lilist" className={"main-container li"+layout} key={post.id}>

                                    <img src='https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1378/PNG/512/avatardefault_92824.png'/>

                                    <footer>                                       
                                        <strong>{post.title}</strong>                                       
                                    </footer>

                                </li>
                            </Link>
                        ))}     
                    </ul>     
                    ) : (
                        <div className="empty">Nenhum Post :(</div>
                    ) }    
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.posts
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
bindActionCreators(DataActions, dispatch);


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Main);
```

---

No arquivo Main.js quando a funcao loadDados() executa,

ela chama a funcao do action:

```
dataSave(response.data);
```

mas quando executo:

```
console.log(posts);
```

fica como undefined :(

O que sera que estou fazendo de errado?

repositorio no github: https://github.com/felipeagger/React-Redux/tree/redux

> Branch redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementei seu código [no CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-architecture-xo1ii), ignorando algumas partes que faltavam.

Quase sempre que, ao usar o react-redux, uma ação disparada aparentemente não fizer nenhum efeito no store, é porque o `dispatch` não está sendo utilizado. De duas, uma:

1) você está importando em seu componente uma ação definida na pasta **actions**, sem envolvê-la num `dispatch`, através de `mapDispatchToProps`. Isso você fez corretamente.

2) você não está usando a função `dispatch` dentro da **action creator**. Esse foi seu caso! Você retorna o objeto que representa a ação ao invés de despachá-la ao store. O correto é:

```js
export const dataSave = posts => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_POSTS',
        payload: { posts }
    })
}
```

Além disso, algumas observações:

- a ação é enviada ao store, que atualiza o componente com o novo valor. No entanto, não espere que este identificador obtenha o novo valor imediatamente após chamar `dataSave(response.data)`. O que ela faz é solicitar ao store que modifique seu estado e, após algum tempo, o React irá reagir a essa mudança e chamar o método render deste componente com o novo `posts`.
- cada reducer deve possuir um estado inicial que irá evoluir com o tempo. Como você usou `combineReducers`, o state inicial é `state: { posts: [] }`. Porém, o reducer posts irá alterar a subárvore posts, não o state inteiro. Logo, o correto seria utilizar algo como o seguinte

```js
// reducers/posts.js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  list: []
};

export default function posts(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_POSTS":
      return { ...state, list: action.payload.posts };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// pages/Main.js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.posts.list
});
```